# Empty Array Issue

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've read through the other empty array articles and can not find my solution to my issue. I have this array (below).

```
<?php    

   $args=array(

  'post_type' => 'vehicle-brochure',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order'=>'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(

            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brochure-bucket',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => 655,
                ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brochure-bucket',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => 605,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
                 )
     ),
    ); 
?>
```

**What I'm trying at the moment.**

```
<?php if(!empty($args)):
    echo "x";
else:
    echo "y";
endif; ?>
```

Comment: How are you getting the return value you mentioned?

Comment: Actually, you haven't opened php tags before you set the $args. Are these the same file or different?

Comment: I corrected that thank you - this isn't my whole page so I wrote it wrong here.

I'm getting the 1112, 4 or name by either using a foreach, print_r or count statements in or out of a while statement.

Comment: you don't need to have a `<? ... ?>` for EVERY line of code. it's a major waste of time typing them all, and makes the code much harder to read. open `<?php` ONCE, write all the php code you have then, close `?>` it ONCE.

Comment: Would it be easier to troubleshoot with the whole page 65 lines total - I've been dinged before for being too verbose. So I tried to keep this question simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I just needed to step away from it - easy solution.

```
<?php $args = array(); ?>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>    // WHAT I WAS MISSING
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>      // WHAT I WAS MISSING

       // WHAT TO SHOW IF THERE'S ANY POSTS //

<?php endif; ?> //Fail, like I want if nothing is found.
```